In which Vedic Mantra of Kanvasakha Radha was mentioned?
Brahmavaivarta Purana says that Radha was mentioned in the Kanvasakha of the Vedas.

Now I want to listen to the unprecedented story of Radhika as described in the Vedas and praised by you and also brought out in the Kanvasakha. You have already admitted while speaking on the other scriptures. - Brahmavaivarta Purana, Prakriti Khanda, Chapter 48, Verse 11-12.

Can someone refer to those Vedic mantras (from the Kanvasakha recension) in which Radha was mentioned?
